# How can I construe a radius of convergence of 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just showed that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^nx^n}$ is $r=0$ does that mean it does not converge at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It means that it converges if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: Could one say that if $r=0$ , then it only converges in the expansion point. Here $a=0$ since $(x-0)^n=x^n$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Radius of convergence $r$ means $$r=\sup_{x}\left\{|x|: \sum n^n x^n< \infty\right\}$$ That is, $r$ is the supremum of  $|x|$  over all number $x$ for which the series converges. Here $r=0$ means the the series converges only  at $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

It converges for $x=0$ but not for any other value of $x$.